# Which of the follwing is true while reading the sentence

Tags: word-meaning

> LA weather is perfect, but Houston has 4 seasons. The beach in galveston is warm enough to swim. Santa Monica beach is too cold for me even in summer. House in Houston very affordable. Job in Houston is very much. Houston has no state tax. I **traded earthquake with hurricane too** .lol.

Does it mean " I prefer hurricane to earthquake" ? 
Or
Does it mean " I live in LA and I am going to suffer from an earthquake and if I had stayed in Houston I would not be concerned about a possible earthquake in LA"

Answer (score 1):

From this short passage there are a few things I learn about the author:

The author recently moved from Los Angeles to Houston. While LA has good weather, Houston has its own numerous advantages. He is also saying that he "traded" earthquakes (common in LA) for hurricanes (common in Houston). The preposition "for" should've been used instead of "with".

Answer (score 0):

It means the person in question has exchanged the risk of being victim to an earthquake (common in LA) with the risk of being victim to a hurricane (common in Texas) . They are making something of a joke of it, as shown by the 'lol'.

Comment: That's what it means, but it's worth pointing out that it's very poorly worded as is.